# Live Tile like Animation

Tags: c#, storyboard, uwp

I'm trying to recreate the slide-up part animation of the notification-queue on Windows 10 live tiles with an image I have ontop of another image. Below I have a "slide-up" storyboard working...but it's not the same.

Is the live tile ani actually growing in height as it slides up over the first?

I can't "see/figure" what it's doing.

```
public static async Task SlideUp(FrameworkElement element, double duration, int to = 0)
    {
        var tempTransform = new TranslateTransform();
        element.RenderTransform = tempTransform;
        var animation = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            From = element.ActualHeight * 2,
            To = to,
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration),
            EasingFunction = new CubicEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut }
        };

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "Y");
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, tempTransform);
        var sb = new Storyboard();
        sb.Duration = animation.Duration;
        sb.Children.Add(animation);
        await sb.BeginAsync();
    }
```

The flip part of the animations would be nice too.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames class:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.doubleanimationusingkeyframes.aspx

**Update:** You can also animate the Height of the image

```
public static async Task SlideUp(FrameworkElement element, double duration, int to = 0)
{
    var trTransform = new TranslateTransform();
    element.RenderTransform = trTransform;
    double from = element.ActualHeight;
    duration *= 1.5;



    var animation = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
    animation.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame
    {
        KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0)),
        Value = from / 2
    });
    var ks = new KeySpline { ControlPoint1 = new Point(0.0, 0.0), ControlPoint2 = new Point(0.9, 0.1) };
    animation.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineDoubleKeyFrame
    {
        KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(duration*1000/2)),
        KeySpline = ks,
        Value = (from - to) / 3 + to
    });
    var ks2 = new KeySpline { ControlPoint1 = new Point(0.1, 0.9), ControlPoint2 = new Point(0.2, 1.0) };
    animation.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineDoubleKeyFrame
    {
        KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration)),
        KeySpline = ks2,
        Value = to
    });
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "Y");
    Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, trTransform);
    var sb = new Storyboard();
    sb.Duration = animation.Duration;
    sb.Children.Add(animation);



    DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames resizeHeightAnimation = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames()
    {
        EnableDependentAnimation = true
    };
    resizeHeightAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame
    {
        KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0)),
        Value = 0
    });
    var heightSpline1 = new KeySpline { ControlPoint1 = new Point(0.0, 0.0), ControlPoint2 = new Point(0.9, 0.1) };
    resizeHeightAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineDoubleKeyFrame
    {
        KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(duration * 1000 / 2)),
        KeySpline = heightSpline1,
        Value = from / 3
    });
    var heightSpline2 = new KeySpline { ControlPoint1 = new Point(0.1, 0.9), ControlPoint2 = new Point(0.2, 1.0) };
    resizeHeightAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineDoubleKeyFrame
    {
        KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration)),
        KeySpline = heightSpline2,
        Value = from
    });
    Storyboard.SetTarget(resizeHeightAnimation, element);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(resizeHeightAnimation, "RenderTransform.Height");
    sb.Children.Add(resizeHeightAnimation);


    sb.Begin();
}
```

If that looks to laggy for you, you can also try setting the VerticalAlignment of the element to Bottom and remove the position animation part of the method.

Comment: The easing effect is perfect, but the sliding up starts below the image it's on topof. Changed  from = element.ActualHeight*2 to -  from = element.ActualHeight, still starts it from below. The image has to appear to be growing from the bottom- until it fills the one underneath.it.

Comment: Ok, so there also needs to be a height animation, I updated the solution.